# "dotnet build/msbuild/run" under linux fails as AD domain joined user

Tags: linux, active-directory, .net-core

I'm using a template ASP.Net Core 2.1 (preview) project -- literally no code other than what's included in the template.  JetBrains Rider failed to build/run the application so I dropped to terminal and ran `dotnet build` in the folder; no dice.  However, `sudo dotnet build` worked just fine.

I switched to 2.1 preview while troubleshooting this issue originally on 2.0.6 (my project needed 2.1 as it was, but the behavior was observed in both versions).

I had a suspicion that it was *related* to the fact that I use a domain account to login to my computer (`whoami` reports `HOMEDOMAIN\domain_user`, not `domain_user@homedomain.local`).  I've had other applications behave strangely when using my domain credentials, so I logged in with a local account and `dotnet build` works, as does running `sudo -u (any local account) dotnet build` when logged in with the domain account.

The following is the output from `dotnet build`:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300-preview1-008174/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error MSB3883: Unexpected exception:  [/home/HOMEDOMAIN/domain_user/RiderProjects/Intonation/Intonation/Intonation.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300-preview1-008174/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error : System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect) ---> System.IO.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect [/home/HOMEDOMAIN/domain_user/RiderProjects/Intonation/Intonation/Intonation.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300-preview1-008174/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error : at System.Threading.Mutex.CreateMutexCore(Boolean initiallyOwned, String name, Boolean& createdNew) [/home/HOMEDOMAIN/domain_user/RiderProjects/Intonation/Intonation/Intonation.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300-preview1-008174/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error : at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.BuildServerConnection.<RunServerCompilationCore>d__7.MoveNext() [/home/HOMEDOMAIN/domain_user/RiderProjects/Intonation/Intonation/Intonation.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300-preview1-008174/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error : --- End of inner exception stack trace --- [/home/HOMEDOMAIN/domain_user/RiderProjects/Intonation/Intonation/Intonation.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300-preview1-008174/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error : at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) [/home/HOMEDOMAIN/domain_user/RiderProjects/Intonation/Intonation/Intonation.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300-preview1-008174/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error : at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(CancellationToken cancellationToken) [/home/HOMEDOMAIN/domain_user/RiderProjects/Intonation/Intonation/Intonation.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300-preview1-008174/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error : at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.ManagedCompiler.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands) [/home/HOMEDOMAIN/domain_user/RiderProjects/Intonation/Intonation/Intonation.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300-preview1-008174/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error : ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.IO.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect [/home/HOMEDOMAIN/domain_user/RiderProjects/Intonation/Intonation/Intonation.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300-preview1-008174/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error : at System.Threading.Mutex.CreateMutexCore(Boolean initiallyOwned, String name, Boolean& createdNew) [/home/HOMEDOMAIN/domain_user/RiderProjects/Intonation/Intonation/Intonation.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300-preview1-008174/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error : at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.BuildServerConnection.<RunServerCompilationCore>d__7.MoveNext()<--- [/home/HOMEDOMAIN/domain_user/RiderProjects/Intonation/Intonation/Intonation.csproj]
```

I did a build with diagnostic output and grepped the output for paths; all were there and accessible (the file is enormous; happy to put it on github if anyone thinks there's value there)

My linux box is OpenSUSE Tumbleweed:

```
Linux laptop 4.15.10-1-default #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 15 20:31:17 UTC 2018 (5e4329c) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm using sssd for domain login handling, and my `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` is:

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
services = pam,nss
domains = homedomain.local
default_domain_suffix = homedomain.local
debug_level = 3
[pam]
[nss]
[domain/homedomain.local]
id_provider = ad
auth_provider = ad
enumerate = false
cache_credentials = true
case_sensitive = false
ad_server = dc.homedomain.local
ad_hostname = laptop.homedomain.local
debug_level = 3
override_homedir = /home/%F/%u
ldap_user_shell = loginShell
[domain/default]
auth_provider = krb5
chpass_provider = krb5
krb5_realm = HOMEDOMAIN.LOCAL
krb5_server = DC.homedomain.local
krb5_validate = False
krb5_renewable_lifetime = 1d
krb5_lifetime = 1d
```

I'm stumped and somewhat clueless about what other bits of information would be helpful in diagnosing this so if there's something else I can provide; happy to add anything if it'll be helpful.

**EDIT:**

As suggested below, adding `/p:UseSharedCompilation=false` results in the build succeeding as the domain user; I'm opening a bug with the project as suggested.

Comment: Could you try to add `/p:UseSharedCompilation=false`? If It builds, do open an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn as it seems like a bug in the new compiler server connection.

Comment: @MartinUllrich - `/p:UseSharedCompilation=false` did the trick.  I'll update the question and open up a bug over there as you suggested.  Many thanks!!!